# "I have not given {or/nor} received any information"?

Tags: verbs, neither-nor

Is it correct to say "I have not given or received any information about the party"?

Or is it correct to say "I have not given **nor** received any information about the party"?

Answer (score 2):

A difficult one. There are many articles on the web about the correct usage of "nor". For example:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/should-i-use-or-or-nor

Grammar Girl writes:

> If, on the other hand, the second part of the negative is a verb phrase then you can choose to use “nor” or “or”.

This sentence appears correct:

> I have not (given or received) any information about the party

And this sentence seems to be emphatic, by stressing the negative aspect:

> I have not given **nor** received any information about the party

From the perspective of logic:
! (a || b)
and
!a && !b
are the same.